# Excel Macro: To take effect on another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, macros

i written a macro and save as mymacro.xlsm. the excel file i want to process with my macro has arbitrary name as it is pulled from the system. lets call it file_today. currently the way i run is to open mymacro.xlsm and file_today.xls. From file_today.xls i will execute mymacro.xlsm. 
is there a way to run my macro on my file (lets say tomorrow will be different filename) automatically. tq.

Comment: You can setup a folder to be checked for files and tell your macro to run on any files in this folder, obviously your macro file will still need to be opened but it could be setup on a schedule or something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+file+properties

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you are clever about naming your data files.  For example if the files in a specific folder are named like:

```
20160521Data.xls
```

Then the macro can:

1. open the folder
2. find the file with the proper date *(encoded in the filename)*
3. open the file